# Solve ODE system efficiently with mathematica

Tags: differential-equations, scripting

I've been trying to solve a system of ODE's with mathematica, which is a master equation of a hierarchically organized tissue model, where I want to quantify the number of cells at level 'k' with 'm' number of mutations at a given time point.
Here is the equation itself:
$dN_{k,m}(t)/dt =\delta_{k-1} (\frac{N_{k-1,m}(t)}{N_{k-1}} - \frac{N_{k,m}(t)}{N_{k}}
  + \mu ( \frac{(N_{k-1,m-1}(t)-N_{k-1,m}(t))}{N_{k-1}} - 2\frac{(N_{k,m-1}(t)-N_{k,m}(t))}{N_{k}} ) )
 + \delta_{k} \mu \frac{(N_{k,m-1}(t)-N_{k,m}(t))}{N_{k}}$

Where the $\delta_k, \mu,N_k$ are fixed parameters.

My problem is that I have not found any solution to solve this system of equations as compact as possible, because I want to calculate all states in time for arbitrary number of levels (k) and mutation numbers (m).

Here is the code what I tried already which is not correct:

```
n = 3;
g = 4.0;
delta = Array[(1.0/g)^(n - #) &, n + 1] /. x_ /; x > 1 -> 2;
Nk = Array[1000 &, n + 1];
maxMut = 10;
mu = 0.001;
Nt[k_, m_] := 
 delta[[k - 1]] * (Nt[k - 1, m]/Nk[[k - 1]] - Nt[k, m]/Nk[[k]]
       + mu * ( (Nt[k, m - 1] - Nt[k - 1, m])/Nk[[k - 1]] - 
        2*(Nt[k, m - 1] - Nt[k, m])/Nk[[k]] ) ) + 
  delta[[k]] * mu * (Nt[k, m - 1] - Nt[k, m])/Nk[[k]]

Nt[1, m_] := delta[[1]] * mu * (Nt[1, m - 1] - Nt[1, m])/Nk[[1]]
Nt[k_, 0] := 
 delta[[k - 1]] * (Nt[k - 1, 0]/Nk[[k - 1]] - Nt[k, 0]/Nk[[k]])
```

So I want to compact this as a system of ODE's in a form similarly like this, to put it into a list for NDSolve...

I tried in a bruteforce manner to solve the system for just n=3 levels such as:

```
Eq1 = capn0null[t]' == -delta[[1]]*mu*(capn0null[t])/Nk[[1]];
Eq2 = capn01[t]' == delta[[1]]*mu*(capn0null[t] - capn01[t])/Nk[[1]];
Eq3 = capn02[t]' == delta[[1]]*mu*(capn01[t] - capn02[t])/Nk[[1]];


Eq4 = capn1null[t]' == 
   delta[[1]]*(capn0null[t]/Nk[[1]] - capn1null[t]/Nk[[2]] + 
       mu*((0 - capn0null[t])/Nk[[1]] - 
          2*(0 - capn1null[t])/Nk[[2]])) + 
    delta[[2]]*mu*(0 - capn1null[t])/Nk[[2]];
Eq5 = capn11[t]' == 
   delta[[1]]*(capn01[t]/Nk[[1]] - capn11[t]/Nk[[2]] + 
       mu*((capn1null[t] - capn01[t])/Nk[[1]] - 
          2*(capn1null[t] - capn11[t])/Nk[[2]])) + 
    delta[[2]]*mu*(capn1null[t] - capn01[t])/Nk[[2]];

Eq6 = capn12[t]' == 
   delta[[1]]*(capn02[t]/Nk[[1]] - capn12[t]/Nk[[2]] + 
       mu*((capn11[t] - capn02[t])/Nk[[1]] - 
          2*(capn11[t] - capn12[t])/Nk[[2]])) + 
    delta[[2]]*mu*(capn11[t] - capn02[t])/Nk[[2]];



Eq7 = capn2null[t]' == 
   delta[[2]]*(capn1null[t]/Nk[[2]] - capn2null[t]/Nk[[3]] + 
       mu*((0 - capn1null[t])/Nk[[2]] - 
          2*(0 - capn2null[t])/Nk[[3]])) + 
    delta[[3]]*mu*(0 - capn2null[t])/Nk[[3]];
Eq8 = capn21[t]' == 
   delta[[2]]*(capn11[t]/Nk[[2]] - capn21[t]/Nk[[3]] + 
       mu*((capn2null - capn11[t])/Nk[[2]] - 
          2*(capn2null[t] - capn21[t])/Nk[[3]])) + 
    delta[[3]]*mu*(capn2null[t] - capn21[t])/Nk[[3]];


Eq9 = capn22[t]' == 
   delta[[2]]*(capn12[t]/Nk[[2]] - capn22[t]/Nk[[3]] + 
       mu*((capn21 - capn12[t])/Nk[[2]] - 
          2*(capn21[t] - capn22[t])/Nk[[3]])) + 
    delta[[3]]*mu*(capn21[t] - capn22[t])/Nk[[3]];




Eq10 = capn3null[t]' == 
   delta[[3]]*(capn2null[t]/Nk[[3]] - capn3null[t]/Nk[[4]] + 
       mu*((0 - capn2null[t])/Nk[[3]] - 
          2*(0 - capn3null[t])/Nk[[4]])) + 
    delta[[4]]*mu*(0 - capn3null[t])/Nk[[4]];
Eq11 = capn31[t]' == 
   delta[[3]]*(capn21[t]/Nk[[3]] - capn31[t]/Nk[[4]] + 
       mu*((capn3null - capn21[t])/Nk[[3]] - 
          2*(capn3null[t] - capn31[t])/Nk[[4]])) + 
    delta[[4]]*mu*(capn3null[t] - capn31[t])/Nk[[4]];


Eq12 = capn32[t]' == 
   delta[[3]]*(capn22[t]/Nk[[3]] - capn32[t]/Nk[[4]] + 
       mu*((capn31 - capn22[t])/Nk[[3]] - 
          2*(capn31[t] - capn32[t])/Nk[[4]])) + 
    delta[[4]]*mu*(capn31[t] - capn32[t])/Nk[[4]];

sol = NDSolve[{Eq1, Eq2, Eq3, Eq4, Eq5, Eq6, Eq7, Eq8, Eq9, Eq10, 
   Eq11, Eq12, capn0null[0] == Nk[[1]], capn1null[0] == Nk[[2]], 
   capn2null[0] == Nk[[3]], capn3null[0] == Nk[[4]], capn01[0] == 0, 
   capn11[0] == 0, capn21[0] == 0, capn31[0] == 0, capn02[0] == 0, 
   capn12[0] == 0, capn22[0] == 0, capn32[0] == 0}, {capn0null[t], 
   capn1null[t], capn2null[t], capn3null[t], capn01[t], capn11[t], 
   capn21[t], capn31[t], capn02[t], capn12[t], capn22[t], 
   capn32[t]}, {t, 0, tlife}]
```

But I get an error also:
[image: error message]

Sorry if its an already answered question but I just found topics which is not that closely related to this particular problem.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: The last line of your first block of code contains  `Nt[ k_, 0] := ... Nt[ k, 0] ...`, which is problematic.  How should `Nt[ 1, 0 ]` be calculated ?

Comment: There are two syntax errors in your second block of code.  The error message comes from writing the derivative `f[t]'`.  It should be `f'[t]`, where `f` stands for your 12 functions of time.  The second syntax error is using `f` instead of `f[t]` on the RHS of your equations, where `f` stands for 4 of your dynamic variables.  With those changes and adding `tlife = 10` your second block of code ran for me.

Comment: Thank you, it works now with the bruteforce solution, in the light of this I try to generalize it! Pretty newby errors but its a start:)

Comment: @DemeterMárton You have not answered the question. How should `Nt[ 1, 0 ]` be calculated ?

Comment: Oh, sorry, it is: Nt[1,0] := delta[[1]] * mu * (0 - Nt[1, 0])/Nk[[1]], because the number of cells with mutation number -1 is zero. This equation means that the number of "wild type" cells, which has zero mutations is decreasing as they gain mutations in the stem cell level (level 0), as there is no such level which can supply the stem cells below (level -1 not exists).

Comment: @DemeterMárton What are the limits for `k` and `m`?

Comment: m can tend to inf, n (number of levels) also but it has an optimum at $n^{*}=\mathrm{log}_2(N)$ where N is the number of cells the tissue produces over the lifetime (tlife), where $\mathrm{tlife} = NN_0 /\delta_{n-1}$ where usually we set $\delta_{n-1}=1$ and $N_0$ is the number of stem cells. So it is reasonable to think the ranges as m={0,inf} and n = {1,n*}.